# Can I use .crd and .dwg files as QGIS data sources?

Tags: qgis, layers, autocad, file-formats

I  want to use my autocad files(.dwg) and my field files (.crd), and want to know if they are compatible with qgis.

Comment: You will want to convert to a DXF file which QGIS can work with.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-import-a-dwg-into-a-qgis-project & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/import-cdr-file-into-gis-cad-format

Comment: Bear in mind the version of the DXF files. In my experience Qgis and some versions of ArcMap can only read version 2004 and previous. Sometimes the file sems to be availabe to be open, but they do not dispaly any information at all.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I've **read** (never tested) that OGR built with the Open Design Alliance Teiga library (http://www.gdal.org/drv_dwg.html) could work. Does any one have some experience with that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is you need to convert these formats to DXF format first. After that it can be possible to load into QGIS - as far as it follows standards and preferably older versions of these standards.

But there are many issues related to it coming from differences between CAD formats and GIS formats:

1. QGIS doesn't care about styles / colours in DXF and is generally able to import only points, lines and polygons (and somehow a bit other objects if you are lucky)
2. QGIS doesn't care about layers in DXF and elevation data - by importing the file you simply loose all that information